# Why can't my Arduino Uno digitalRead() the digitalWrite() from other I/O pins?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I want to do something very basic as shown below:

```
#define READ_PIN    7
#define WRITE_PIN   8

void setup() {
  pinMode(READ_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(WRITE_PIN, LOW);
  Serial.println(digitalRead(READ_PIN));
}
```

I am bridging the WRITE_PIN and READ_PIN together to read what the pin is outputting.

The input always reads '1' as expected with INPUT_PULLUP, but I would like it to read '0'. I get the same results using `analogRead()` and `analogWrite()`, no matter which pins I use.

Does anybody know why this seems impossible to achieve?

Comment: I re-read this question three times and I still can't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you enable the internal pullup resistors and you leave the input pin not connected there's no way to read a 0 out of that port - it's pulled up to high logical level by the internal pullup, you asked for it! If you want to read a zero disable the pullup and physically connect the pin to ground.

Comment: I clarified my post. Left out an important part, where the pins are bridged together.

Comment: Well, it was quite an important detail :-) . Still, you are missing the `pinMode(WRITE_PIN, OUTPUT);` in `setup` - pins on AVR Arduino are in `INPUT` mode by default (although it's always good practice to state explicitly the requested mode in `setup`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moving from the comment)

Pin mode on Arduino is set to `INPUT` by default<sup>1</sup>; to use `WRITE_PIN` as an output you have to explicitly set it as such in `setup`.

```
pinMode(WRITE_PIN, OUTPUT);
```

---

1. It's worth saying that, even if the default is documented, it's still good practice to always set explicitly the mode of all the pins in the setup, even input ones, for clarity.